# Why is keyboard.nextLine() being skipped inside of this for loop? (java)

Tags: java

### This is my code thus far:

```
System.out.println("How many different types of food do the gerbils eat?");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberofitems = keyboard.nextInt();


String[] fooditems = new String[numberofitems];

  for(int i=0; i<fooditems.length; i++){

      System.out.println("Name of food item " + (i+1) + ":");

      fooditems[i]= keyboard.nextLine();
  }
```

### This is what the system output looks like:

*How many different types of food do the gerbils eat?*

*5*

*Name of food item 1:*

*Name of food item 2:*

*Red Pill*

*Name of food item 3:*

*Blue Pill*

*Name of food item 4:*

*Green Pill*

*Name of food item 5:*

*Orange Pill*

The number 5 and the different food names were just random user input when prompted.

Why is it not letting me input a name for food item 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a nextLine() after the nextInt() to clear the buffer.
Try this code :

```
System.out.println("How many different types of food do the gerbils eat?");

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int numberofitems = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();


String[] fooditems = new String[numberofitems];

for(int i=0; i<fooditems.length; i++){

  System.out.println("Name of food item " + (i+1) + ":");

  fooditems[i]= keyboard.nextLine();
```

}

Comment: Thank you, I entered this code and it worked! What would I do if I wanted to put more than one array in the for loop? For example, what if my code needed me to ask two separate questions inside of the for loop? And I wanted to store something in two different arrays? So, after the "fooditems[i]= keyboard.nextLine();" there would be another question about the amount of that food each gerbil can eat, and then another array like "amounts[i]= keyboard.nextLine();" ... would that work?

Comment: A good way to find out would be to try it yourself. (But I think it would mostly work, yes)
If you think my answer was good/helpful, I'd appreciate it if you upvoted it.

Comment: It says I can't upvote anything until I have 15 reputation. I'm sorry... I'm a new user. I will upvote your answer as soon as I get 15 rep!

Comment: @user3550612 `nextInt` only reads a number and then stops; the newline is still in the `Scanner`'s buffer. Any time that you need to move past the newline character in a prompt-response situation, you can call `nextLine` there to consume the rest of the line in the buffer. I strongly suggest learning to use an IDE and debugger so you can step through and watch what's being read when you have problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's reading the rest of the (empty) line after the 5. Add another call before the loop to consume the newline.

Comment: What do you mean by add another call? I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced with this yet.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the number 5, the input still has the newline character in the buffer, which means your next call to `nextLine()` reads the input to the next newline, which reads a blank.

Instead, consume the rest of the line after reading the number, by adding this line:

```
keyboard.nextLine();
```